# How many orthogonal matrices map one vector to another?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Say you have two real vectors $u$ and $v$ and $\|u\| = \|v\|$

How many real square and orthogonal matrices $A$ are there such that $Au = v$?  Assuming $u$ and $v$ are not parallel/antiparallel, there are at least two, because you can do the mapping with a reflection ($\det(A) = -1$) or a rotation ($\det(A) = 1$).  But I don't know how to prove (or not) that that's an upper bound.

Comment: same answer when $u=v.$ You might as well take $u=v=e_n$ the final unit vector in a standard basis. The resulting matirx is an $(n-1)$ by $(n-1)$ orthogonal matrix in the upper left, then an isolated $1$ at bottom right

Comment: There are an infinite number. In particular, any Euler rotation whose first step rotates $u$ in the direction of $v$, and then performs a rotation around $v$, will satisfy $Au=v$, and there are (at least in 3 dimensions or higher) an infinite number of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in seeking to answer *how many?* in this context, except for the low-dimension cases $n=1$ and $n=2$ the cardinality of the set of suitable matrices does not give much useful information. however, the dimension of a manifold is another measure of "size".

the $n \times n$ matrices constitute a linear space of dimension $n^2$. the requirements for a matrix to be orthogonal impose $1+2+\dots+n = \frac12 n(n+1)$ constraints, whilst the equations $Au=v$ impose a further $n-1$ constraints (since ||v|| is fixed). thus after these conditions are satisfied the number of remaining degrees of freedom is:
$$
n^2 - \left( \frac12 n(n+1) + n-1 \right) = \frac12(n-1)(n-2)
$$
this may be interpreted as the dimension of the submanifold of $Mat_n(\mathbb{R})$ which contains exactly those orthogonal matrices which map $u$ to $v$

Answer (score 2):

There are an uncountably infinite number.

In particular, any Euler rotation whose first step rotates $u$ in the direction of $v$, and then performs a rotation around $v$, will satisfy $Au=v$, and there are (at least in 3 dimensions or higher) an infinite number of such Euler rotation matrices.

Here is an example in Mathematica:

```
u = {1, 2, 3};
v = {3, 1, 2};
RotationMatrix[RandomReal[], v].RotationMatrix[{u, v}].u
```

The output is always `{3,1,2}`, irregardless of the value of `RandomReal[]`.

Comment: Ah, simple once I see it :)  Thanks!